# How does this series of keystrokes in vim delete everything but the numbered lines?

Tags: vim

Working through this [just the middle](http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/54862fbb3f90ac0002904cf5) kata,

```
Leave only the
numbered lines.
LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
That's all.
Thank you
very much.
```

the following keystroke sequence makes sense and does something in the buffer:

```
djGd2kZZ
```

It's basically chaining commands together.  But what is the following doing exactly, and why can't I see it in the buffer?  I tried omitting the "q!" (quit?) command but then it didn't work.

```
)3:wq!<CR>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`)` is a [motion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#)) which jumps forward one sentence. A sentence is:

```
*sentence*

    A sentence is defined as ending at a '.', '!' or '?' followed by either the
    end of a line, or by a space or tab.
```

In this file:

```
Leave only the
numbered lines.
LINE1
```

The first two lines are a sentence ending in a dot and a newline, so `)` moves cursor to the beginning of `LINE 1`.

`:wq!<CR>` is the common sequence to save and quit, overwriting without prompting.

The trick is that `:w` [accepts a range command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:w)

```
:[range]w[rite][!] [++opt]

    Write the specified lines to the current file.  This
    is unusual, because the file will not contain all
    lines in the buffer.
```

And putting a number before `:` is `N:` [Count and Range](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#N:)

```
Count and Range                     *N:*

    When giving a count before entering ":", this is translated into:
        :.,.+(count - 1)

    In words: The 'count' lines at and after the cursor.  Example: To delete
    three lines:
        3:d<CR>    is translated into: .,.+2d<CR>
```

`3:w` becomes `:.,.+2w` meaning write the current line and the following two lines.

`)3:wq!<CR>` does not *delete everything but the numbered lines*, it *saves the numbered lines over the original file*. The rest of the text is lost when Vim force-quits. That's why you can't see the buffer change - it doesn't change.

(After a while I got `djGd2kZZ` on my own for this one as well, and didn't know you could do [range]:w until I saw the shorter answers).